# Cordova Code-Push issue with ios automatically rolling back

Tags: html, ios, cordova, code-push

I installed the code-push (microsoft) plugin for Cordova to be able to update an android and ios hybrid app on the fly. I pushed an update to both Android and IOS. The update to the Android app worked well and the app is still updates after killing the app and restarting it. The IOS version updated and worked until I killed the app. Once restarted the app was back to the original version.

When using the code-push cli, the IOS push always is only showing pending updates and never indicates that any of them were successful. The Android version lists that the updates completed successfully.

For set up all I did was install the plugin, build the app, and call the sync method in the on device ready function.

I anyone has experience with code-push, I would very much appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the console logs in the Safari dev tools? The `sync` method logs a bunch of messages to help indicate if and why an issue is occurring during the download or installation process of an update.

Comment: I have same problem!